# Meaning of two low battery screens on Acer Iconia tablet?

Tags: battery, charging

According to https://community.acer.com/en/t5/Android-Tablets/Iconia-tab-10-A3-A20-won-t-charge/m-p/513098/highlight/true,

> Hello, my tablet was working fine for a year and suddenly won't charge up.
>
> When plugged in while turned off, the screen will power up, showing the empty battery icon then another icon with a low battery and a power plug.
>
> Then the screen will turn off and start over alternating both icons and so on.

I am going to upload the two screens the OP was talking about:

> [image] [image]
> "Empty battery icon" // "Icon with a low battery and a power plug"

Do the two screens have different meanings?  If yes, then what do they mean?  Are they "charging" and "connect to power"?

Comment: I'd go with your conclusion. Similar, although not identical happens on my Nokia 7.2. If it is fully empty and I try to turn it on, I get that icon (second one with wide and plug). And when I connect power in such a state, it shows the first icon for some time before it gets some charge and then moves me to the charging screen as defined in the device's ROM or firmware. Somebody told me earlier that this is a CPU's screen which is used when the battery is extremely low.

Comment: The right image I would interpret as "device has low battery and was disconnected from power". This could mean that the charger, the charging cable or the usb port in the device is defect. The first two can be checked easily by replacing them. If the USB port in the device is broken it will get difficult as this requires to replace the board that holds the USB port (if it is replaceable) or re-soldering the loose USB port.

Comment: @Robert - you mean the second image?  Is it like iPhone's screen with a red battery, lightning bolt, and a charger?

Comment: @singhnsk If you are saying "similar but not same", then why are you talking about the "same" icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singhnsk says:

> I'd go with your conclusion. Similar, although not identical happens on my Nokia 7.2. If it is fully empty and I try to turn it on, I get that icon ([second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BP5V.jpg)<sup>2</sup> with wire and plug). And when I connect power in such a state, it shows the [first icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wN8a2.jpg)<sup>1</sup> for some time before it gets some charge and then moves me to the charging screen as defined in the device's ROM or firmware. Somebody told me earlier that this is a CPU's screen which is used when the battery is extremely low.

- <sup>1</sup> "Empty battery icon" (with lightning bolt)
- <sup>2</sup> "Icon with a low battery and a power plug"

---

In this view, the answer is:

1. "Charging, please wait till the battery gets at least 1%."
2. "Battery is dead; connect to power."